# Close Dialogprogress when sms is send

Tags: android, progressdialog

Please help, I want update message and close my dialogprogress when smsmanager is send for spesific activity

```
 @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... values) {
     try {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            publishProgress(i * 10);
            if (ACTIVITY) { // set spesific activity
                if (METHOD SEND SUCCESS) {
                    stateProgressDialog = 1; // CREATE STATUS TO onPOSTEXECUDE for update MESSAGE
                    publishProgress(0);
                    Thread.sleep(0);
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code in YOURPROGRESS method to hide YOURPROGRESS. Just override **onPostExecute()** method and write this code in **AsyncTask**.

```
@override
protected void onPostExecute(){
       YOURPROGRESS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       YOURPROGRESS=null;
       //or do whatever you want

}
```

Comment: that for hide dialog, how about update message on dialogprogress?

Comment: @Ashadi that you can do within your doInbackground() method.